# installing Python package from github into virtual environment works but import fails

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, virtualenv, python-packaging

1. I created a python project named PythonApplication
2. I created a virtual environment env (Python 3.6 (64-bit))
3. I run the following in the virtual environment directory

```
pip install git+git://github.com/BillMills/python-package-example.git
```

I get:
[image]

Looking at the directory structure at

```
..\PythonApplication\PythonApplication\env\Lib\site-packages\myPackage
```

I see
[image]

and

[image]

4. I then add the following code inside PythonApplication.py

```
import myPackage

foo = 6
bar = 7
```

When I run this I get the following error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'somePython'

What did I miss?

Based on Saurav's comment below I re-did the steps. However, after creating the environment I did activate it at the command prompt and ran the pip command inside the activated environment instead of the command prompt. The results did not change.

Someone else commented that github.com/BillMills/python-package-example.git is written in Python 2 and will not work in Python 3. If that is correct, what needs to be changed?

[image]

Comment: did you activate the virtual environment before installing git package?

Comment: The environment is active now. I will redo and double check. Thx

Comment: I am doing the project creation, and the adding of the environment, in Visual Studio. It seems that visual studio activates the virtual environment upon creation. Just to make sure I went thru the steps again and activated the environment at the command prompt and within the environment ran the pip command again. The result did not change. I am updating the question to reflect this.

Comment: would be better to copy paste terminal output rather than uploading screenshots, which are hard to read

Comment: If you downvote, please comment as to why so I know how to improve future questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package you are using from https://github.com/BillMills/python-package-example is using an import style not supported in Python 3. You can see in [python-package-example/__init__.py](https://github.com/BillMills/python-package-example/blob/master/myPackage/__init__.py#L1) that

```
import somePython
```

is used to import a submodule, but python 3 will assume `somePython` exists as a top level module. See [PEP-328](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/2.5.html#pep-328-absolute-and-relative-imports) for a better explanation.

A Python 3 compatible example package can be found at https://github.com/kennethreitz/samplemod. Notice that in [sample/__init__.py](https://github.com/kennethreitz/samplemod/blob/master/sample/__init__.py) submodules are imported using a relative import (indicated by the leading '.'):

```
from .core import hmm
```

If you wanted to modify python-package-example to be compatible you would need to change its __init__.py to use an absolute import:

```
import myPackage.somePython as somePython
```

or a relative import:

```
from . import somePython
```